# Can I restore a plugin that was accidentally deleted? (on localhost)

Tags: plugins, backup

I did something really stupid and accidentally removed a plugin that I've been working on for weeks, with no backups. (I know! Learning moment!)

**Is there any way I can restore this plugin?** It's not in my Windows recycle bin.

I deleted it through the WordPress wp-admin interface. Going to Plugins and clicking **Delete**.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a while ago I used Windows, but don't you have some kind of "_restore points_" like Time-Maschine on Mac you can switch to? Just an idea.. hope you get it fixed!

Comment: No luck for me. Windows system restore points don't restore basic files. I've tried recovery software as well with no luck. No other option than to rewrite my code, this time, using Git!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot answer: It depends.

- If you store your wordpress in a partition which do not contain OS, you get higher chance to recovery it.
- If you has not rebooted your PC, you get higher chance.
- If you've just deleted your plugins, you're likely to be able to recover it.

Try some data recovery softwares (like Recover My Files - Data Recovery) **as soon as posible**. I tried it sometimes in the past and have good result.

Next times, you should use a version control software like `git` and a remote git hosted service like github or bitbucket to save your ass.

Good luck buddy!